# ActionListener actionPerformed called twice

Tags: java, action, onclicklistener

i have this ActionListener:

```
logOutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(getTextFieldContent());

        }
    });
```

and here i add the button to the panel:

```
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
c.gridwidth = 1;
this.add(logOutButton, c);
```

if the content of the JTextField is test,
the console output is:

```
test
test
```

so i think the actionPerformed() method is called twice but why?

### Edit

the hole code:

```
public GuiPanel(){
    super();
    this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10) );
    //Layout:
    GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    this.setLayout(gridbag);
    setUpJButton();

    //label for textfield
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gridbag.setConstraints(labelForName, c);
    this.add(labelForName);

    c.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 0);//padding to top

    //textField
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    setUpTextField();
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gridbag.setConstraints(textField, c);
    c.gridwidth = 1;//reset gridwidth
    this.add(textField);

    c.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0);//padding to top

    //anmelden Button
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
    setUpJButton();
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
    this.add(logInButton, c);

    c.insets = new Insets(10, 5, 0, 0);//padding to left

    //abmelden Button
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    this.add(logOutButton, c);
}

private void setUpJButton() {
    logInButton.setSize(50, 50);
    logInButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(getTextFieldContent());
        }
    });
    logOutButton.setSize(50, 50);
    logOutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(getTextFieldContent());

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Show us the whole code. You probably have another listener attached to `logOutButton`

Comment: `logOutButton.addActionListener(){...}` is probably executed twice, put a breakpoint on it to check.

Comment: @PredragMaric thanks that was the problem :-)

Comment: @YvesHendseth please click the checkmark on the answer by Predrag, as it is identical to the comment that solved your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are calling `setUpJButton()` twice in your code that adds listener twice on same buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out `e.getActionCommand()`. I'm guessing it's two distinct actions on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Since you `instantiate` ActionListener() instance using `new operator` in the addActionListener, it passes `two different instance` (since you call setUpJButton twice) and it (addActionListener) doesn't know that they are same request.

If you sure don't want to extend ActionListener and use like this, then `reference it to an member object and pass` that to addActionListener.
Something like this:

```
ActionListener acLs=new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
           System.out.println(getTextFieldContent());  //getTextFieldContent??
        }
    };
```

Then

```
private void setUpJButton() {
    logInButton.setSize(50, 50);
    logInButton.addActionListener(acLs);
    logOutButton.setSize(50, 50);
    logOutButton.addActionListener(acLs);
}
```